# Re-rendering Ionic React on a route ( don't want to reload the data )

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-hooks, router

I'm trying to build an app with Ionic React. I have an issue with the router.

App.tsx

```
<IonRouterOutlet>
         <Route path="/stats" render={() => <Stats/>} exact={true} />
         <Route path="/orders" component={Orders} exact={true} />
         <Route path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/stats" />} exact={true} /></IonRouterOutlet>
```

In my component Stats, I use useEffect to load the data from the API

```
 useEffect(() => {
   OrdersService.getOrders().then(resultat => {
     setDataOrders(resultat);
    });
     return function cleanup() {
       // Clean the data

     }


  }, []);
```

If I go to my component Orders and go back to stats, react don't reload the data from the API. 
Do you have any solution to force the reload ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: huh?  " ( don't want to reload the data ) " and then in question you say " Do you have any solution to force the reload ?" Not sure what you are asking here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ionic works differently to how you might expect, the routes are rendered even if they have not been entered yet. And when you navigate to a new route, the cleanup function of useEffect does not get called. This is by design so routes are already rendered and good to go when you navigate between pages.

What you want to use is the `useIonViewWillEnter` hook which will be called when the route is about to be entered.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useIonViewWillEnter } from "@ionic/react";

export const DataOrdersView = () => {
  const [dataOrders, setDataOrders] = useState([]);

  useIonViewWillEnter(() => {
    OrdersService.getOrders().then((resultat) => {
      setDataOrders(resultat);
    });
  });

  return <div>Your View</div>;
};
```

You can read more here,
https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/lifecycle

Comment: Thank you so much ! Works fine now !

Comment: Why is it like that? wouldn't this cause a lot of unnecessary renders and hurt performance? In addition, the Dom would be full of invisible, unrelated components.